# how can i implement api gateway in asp.net web api (not .net core) using c#

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, microservices, soa, api-gateway

Now, we developed many services using asp.net web api (not .net core)
we need to develop a gate-way to let the client connect to one end point after that this gateway decide which api to call to process the incoming request and return the response to the client , so web api as a gateway will reroute the request and return the response

client <----> api gateway <----> appropriate web api

We need to develop it simple as possible ,but with best practise using c# and asp.net web api

any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ocelot is powerful library but that is used in.Net Core which helps us build resilient gateway and am not sure of similar Asp.net libraries that you can use in this case . If you are unable to find the suitable library or provider (cloud api gateway providers like azure , AWS ) and you have to write your own gateway api then you have to be aware of few things.

**Best practices for api gateway.**

Api gateway is very useful but at the same time it can be bottle neck. Your gateway should be resilient and highly available. Depending on your request load you may have to implement patterns like "Circuit breaker" , "Retry" and "bulk head" and for that you can use library called Polly. You can log your requests for debugging and performance monitoring. Security is another aspect but really depends how you implement authentication. You may use combination of following libraries to achieve your goal.

https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Comment: Thank you @imran  
but
What is the main idea of api gateway ??

will i make a single controller which contains all methods from each service ?!!
or there is a re-route mechanism for api requests ?

i need some details for coding a gateway

Comment: so gateway api will be separate web api project which can be deployed independently.  it will use http and rest to call other services. one controller or multiple is really upto to you e.g. products call go through on controller,  order calls from other controller. but the calling mechanism should be resilient. if your one of servics is down you can't keep on accumulating requests and that's why i suggested patterns above. the point is api gateway is single point of entry where you can sanitize each request and pass it to your services.

Comment: so, how one can do it ? can you give me a simple code example?
is it mean if i add new function to service , i must add this function to api gateway controller ?? or there is a generic method ? can use database to store each function with it's api url and to lookup when gateway recieve a request ? or what ???

Comment: We don't manage the api redirection in Databases it's an overhead. I am sharing the example with you which in .net core but the idea is exactly the same. The web app in this case is also working as gateway , you can create seperate api gateway api but the fundamental is the same . In the given example the web app is calling distributed service resiliently . https://github.com/EdwinVW/pitstop/tree/master/src/WebApp

Comment: Thank u very much imran,
but now if i add any new function to any service , i must add it to api gateway too
Am i right ???

or what is the other scenarios ?

Comment: That's right . Getting and reading from DB itself is an overhead.

Comment: that's a good question and i was about add comment.  ocelot works based on json so you can configure your mapping there.